# Pass array in c++ function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I would like to ask a question: I want to write a function which I can pass an array to, and then the function can read values from the user and fill the array.

But in fact in every new problem I have different type of array. Sometimes it is int, sometimes it could be also long unsigned.

So I wrote code like this:

```
#include <iostream> 
#define MY_TYPE long long
using namespace std;

void f(MY_TYPE a[ ], MY_TYPE min, MY_TYPE max)
{
    MY_TYPE i;

    for(i = min; i < max; i++)
       cin>>a[i];
}

int main()
{
int x [5], i;
f ( (MY_TYPE*) x,(MY_TYPE) 0,(MY_TYPE) 5);
for(i=0;i<5;i++) cout<< x[i];
}
```

but when I want to run this, after typing the five values, I get a run time error. And it prints nothing on the screen. How can I fix it? Or is there any other way? Any help would be appreciated..thanks

Comment: Maybe you should learn about C++ templates. But not quite sure what you are aksing.

Comment: Forcibly casting a `int x[5];` to a `long long*` will leave you with undefined behavior.

Comment: I thank you all very much...thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using C++, and not C, you should be using C++ containers.

```
#include <array>

void f(std::array<int, 5>& a, size_t start, size_t end)
{
    for (auto i = min; i < max; ++i)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}
```

If you want to use this for *any* type, you have to use a `template`.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void f(std::array<T, N>& a, size_t start, size_t end)
{
    for(auto i = min; i < max; ++i)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 5> integers;
    std::array<float, 10> floats;

    f(integers, 0, integers.size())
    f(floats, 0, floats.size())
}
```

Comment: You forget the size of array in `f`.

Comment: Also since a `std::array` stores its size you do not need to pass size information with it.

Comment: @Jarod42 Not sure what you mean. The size just isn't checked (trying to keep it as similar to the OP's code).

Comment: @NathanOliver What if just only wants to run `f` on a subset of the array? We're not mind-readers here, this is what he had before, I'm just trying to keep it as similar as possible to the OP's code.

Comment: Thanks very much...now i could understand what is going on...thanks

Answer (score 1):

`x` is defined as an array of 5 `int`s.  When you call `f` you cast `x` to a `MY_TYPE*` which is a `long long`.  If `sizeof(int) != sizeof(long long)` then when you traverse the array in `f` you are either going to slice the content of the elements or walk off the end of the array.  If you change `x` to `MY_TYPE x [5]` then it works as it should.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your helping

Answer (score 0):

You define an array of `int`.

```
int x [5], i;
```

and then proceed to use it as if it is an array of `MY_TYPE`:

```
f ( (MY_TYPE*) x,(MY_TYPE) 0,(MY_TYPE) 5);
```

Since`sizeof(int)` is less than `sizeof(MY_TYPE)` in your code, that will lead to accessing memory beyond the valid limits, which leads to undefined behavior. In your case, the UB manifests as a run time error.

Use an array of `MY_TYPE` instead of an array of `int`.

```
MY_TYPE x[5], i;
f ( x, (MY_TYPE) 0, (MY_TYPE) 5);
```

If you know how to use function templates, you can use a function template.

```
template <typename T>
void f(T a[], size_t min, size_t max) // Type of min and max should not
{                                     // depend on T
    size_t i;
    for(i=min;i<max;i++)
       cin>>a[i];
}

int main()
{
   int x [5], i;
   f (x, 0, 5);
   for(i=0;i<5;i++) cout<< x[i];
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help and thanks for that...now it is done